# Records that are false for a particular criteria in ms access query

Tags: ms-access, criteria

I want to get the records that are false for a particular criteria. for example the query criteria for obtaining records where current month has been entered is:
 Year([SalesDate]) = Year(Now()) And Month([SalesDate]) = Month(Now())
but I want to get the records where current month has not been entered.

Comment: You are right but I am looking for records where particularly 'current month' as indicated by the system time is null

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're not looking for records where a particular column is false (a Boolean), but rather where there isn't any data at all (a NULL). I'm not entirely sure what your table structure is, so I'm taking a best guess. If you add in a bit of sample code I might be able to tailor it to you better...

```
SELECT
o.[data] -- Whatever data columns you're wanting to see
FROM orders o
WHERE
o.[SalesDate] IS NULL;
```

Again, I'm not sure how you have your columns organized, so this is a pretty rough stab.